# Using WhenAny in asynchronous programming in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am studying asynchronous programming from microsoft documentation and
I don't understand the following example which uses the WhenAny method:

```
var breakfastTasks = new List<Task> { eggsTask, baconTask, toastTask };
while (breakfastTasks.Count > 0)
{
    Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(breakfastTasks);
    if (finishedTask == eggsTask)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Eggs are ready");
    }
    else if (finishedTask == baconTask)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bacon is ready");
    }
    else if (finishedTask == toastTask)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Toast is ready");
    }
    await finishedTask;
    breakfastTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
}
```

You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/#await-tasks-efficiently).

The problem with this code is that eggsTask refers to a `Task<Egg>` object, baconTask refers to a `Task<Bacon>` object, and toastTask refers to a `Task<Toast>` object.

Then he puts these 3 variables to a List which then is an argument in `Task.WhenAny(breakfastTasks)` method.

Now, I believe that the non-generic overload of WhenAny is used, which you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=net-8.0). Speciffically I believe this overload is used: `public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> WhenAny(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> tasks);`

As you can see the parameter accepts `IEnumerable<Task>`. Also this overload returns a `Task<Task>` object, which when completed becomes a `Task` object. So in this method you put in `Task` objects and when one is completed, the method returns a `Task` object which is the one `Task` object that completed first.

However, when a `Task<Egg>` object completes, it becomes an `Egg` object,
when a `Task<Bacon>` object completes, it becomes a `Bacon` object, and when a `Task<Toast>` object completes, it becomes a `Toast` object.

So, the line below doesn't seem right:

`Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(breakfastTasks);`

Suppose eggsTask completes first, it gives an `Egg` object which is supposed to be returned by the method, but the method when completed returns only a `Task` object.

Could you please explain?

Comment: The return of WhenAny is `Task<Task>`, the await returns the inner Task, which is itself `Task<Egg>`, Awaiting this inner task then gives Egg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this is on the terrible side of example codes from MS. You shouldn't do that in a production code.

Answer (score 3):

The overload of [`Task.WhenAny()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=net-8.0#system-threading-tasks-task-whenany(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-threading-tasks-task)))) you are using has a return type of `Task<Task>`. In combination with the `await` keyword you will get a `Task` reference that finished from the given list of tasks to observe.

This returned `Task` reference is referencing one of your existing task references `eggsTask` (`Task<Egg>`), `baconTask` (`Task<Bacon>`) or `toastTask` (`Task<Toast>`). It does not return any `Egg`, `Bacon` or `Toast` reference. To get the result from the finished task you still have to call `await` on the `Task<...>` instance. As an example, you could wrote

```
if (finishedTask == eggsTask)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Eggs are ready");
    Egg egg = await eggsTask;
}
```

to get the `Egg` reference from that finished task. And since the task is already finished, this `await` call will immediately return the `Egg` reference (and save it in the `egg` variable).

Keep in mind that `Task<TResult>` is extending from `Task`. So all your `Task<Egg>`, `Task<Bacon>` and `Task<Toast>` references could be saved in a variable of type `Task`. This is happening in the line

```
Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(breakfastTasks);
```

However, this will "lose" the ability to get the result from this variable, as there is no generic type anymore. But as long as you have the original task references, you can get the results from these variables instead (`eggsTask`, `baconTask` and `toastTask`) as shown above.